# About conversion of LaTeX file into PDF file

Tags: compiling, windows, texmaker

Whenever I type something in LaTeX and want to view it in PDF, it doesn't yield the required view, even if the file is saved. Instead it gives me an error stating that the file can't be found. Can anyone help me out with this problem? I've downloaded Texmaker for Windows.

Comment: I'm a beginner in this program and having trouble with this convesion.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you installed a TeX distribution like MikTeX or TeXLive? Also, have you tried compiling with F6 when you have set your default compiler as `pdflatex`? On a side note, there is no need to capitalize all letters in your question. This might be interpreted very negatively by some readers. `:)`

Comment: To the downvoters, can you please explain your reason for downvoting? We try to be as nice as possible in this site. I think we need to wait for the OP's reply first. @user24462, can you post a [minimal non-working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) or describe your work-around in more detail?

Comment: @user24462 What exactly is giving the error: Texmaker or LaTeX? What is the file name you are using (some naming can cause issues)?

Answer (score 2):

Downloading of TeXMaker is not enough, because TeXMaker is only an editor (like Notepad, but smarter :) ). You must install MiKTex or TeXLive. These are TeX distributions, which means they provide the program (`pdflatex`) to create a PDF from your LaTeX code (="source code").

This process is usually called "typesetting" and not "conversion to PDF".

When you have installed a TeX distribution, and created a TeX source (code) in your editor, you have to typeset it. (The editor can even be Notepad, but then you have to type stuff in the command line.) When you use TeXMaker, you can hit F1 to typeset, which (if I'm not mistaken) will create the PDF and open the PDF viewer. "Saving" the source does not create the PDF.

Comment: Seriously? _"This process is usually called "typesetting" and not "conversion to PDF""_?

Comment: @xtian Yes. Similar to programming in C++ for example, instead of "convert from source code to executable file", you say "compile" or "build".

Comment: Your example is a term and definition. I'm a noob at LaTeX, so I find _typesetting_ an awkward synonym for _conversion_.